# cannot see RS232 serial data on Raspberry Pi

Tags: serial

I have a Model B Raspberry Pi and an [Serial Pi RS232 Interface](http://www.abelectronics.co.uk/products/3/Raspberry-Pi/29/Serial-Pi-RS232-Interface).  I am running Raspbian Wheezy on my RPi.

I configured the RPi using a [Serial Guide](http://blackeagle.duckdns.org:86/Comp/RPi/Serial.html), with particular attention to the section titled "Reconfigure the RPi console port to to be used as a standard serial port".

I used a null modem to connect a Windows PC to the RPi.  The PC ran TeraTerm and the RPi ran minicom.  I configured both as follows:

Baud Rate = 115200, Data Bits = 8, Parity = NONE, Stop Bits = 1, Flow Control = NONE

This worked perfectly in both directions.

I need to log the data, I assumed something like this would work:

`cat /dev/ttyAMA0 > /var/log/ttyAMA0.log`

But it doesn't log anything.  I tried just this, and nothing is output to the screen:

`cat /dev/ttyAMA0`

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: why don't you run any terminal software on Pi, where you may set up the communication parameters, like baud rate, parity and bit count? "cat" does neither of these.

Comment: Most likely minicom is getting the output of `/dev/ttyAMA0` and you can't get it from `cat` because it's already gone.

Comment: @lenik - I basically want to capture everything from the serial to a file.  I was looking at software like ttylog, however it did not capture anything.  That's when I tried cat as a basic example.

Comment: @MNoit - I am not running minicom at the same time.  Even after a clean reboot I still have the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I posted the question in RPi Forums and it was answered:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=57055&p=431581

I was able to get communications going by running this script:

https://github.com/lurch/rpi-serial-console

More technical details have been posted on the forum thread.